# Query to get data from 3 tables, main tables and sum column from each other 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, aggregate-functions, lateral-join

I'm struggling in query to get data from 3 tables :

Suppliers :

```
supp_id     int
name        nvarchar(200)
phone       nvarchar(10)
location    nvarchar(50)
note        nvarchar(MAX)
date        date
```

suppliers_invoices:

```
ID          int 
supp_id     int 
o_number    nvarchar(50)
price       decimal(18, 2)
note        nvarchar(MAX)
date        date
image       image
```

suppliers_payments:

```
ID        int
supp_id   int
value     decimal(18, 2)
method    nvarchar(30)
note      nvarchar(MAX)
date      date
```

What I'm trying to get is this information:

```
suppliers.supp_id,suppliers.name,suppliers.phone,(sum(suppliers_invoices.price),
(sum(suppliers_payments.value), ((sum(suppliers_invoices.price) - (sum(suppliers_payments.value))
group by suppliers.supp_id.
```

I want to get each supplier invoices price sum and value paid sum.

what I'm getting now is wrong data because I think the price is multiplied by the other table row counts.

this is what I tried :

```
SELECT dbo.suppliers.supp_id, dbo.suppliers.name, dbo.suppliers.phone, 
SUM(dbo.suppliers_invoices.price) AS Expr1, SUM(dbo.suppliers_payments.value) AS Expr2
FROM dbo.suppliers INNER JOIN dbo.suppliers_invoices ON dbo.suppliers.supp_id = 
dbo.suppliers_invoices.supp_id INNER JOIN dbo.suppliers_payments ON dbo.suppliers.supp_id = 
dbo.suppliers_payments.supp_id GROUP BY dbo.suppliers.supp_id, dbo.suppliers.name,dbo.suppliers.phone
```

Here some data I'm testing on :

suppliers:

```
supp_id   name    phone         location    note    date
1         test    0543642256    NULL        NULL    2020-11-17
2         test2   0543642211    NULL        NULL    2020-11-17
```

suppliers_invoices:

```
ID  supp_id   o_number   price      note    date         image     
1   1         123        5000.00    NULL    2020-11-17   NULL
2   1         1235       3000.00    NULL    2020-11-17   NULL
3   2         55         2000.00    NULL    2020-11-17   NULL
```

suppliers_payments:

```
ID  supp_id   value     method    note   date   
1   1         2000.00   cash      NULL   2020-11-17
2   1         2000.00   visa      NULL   2020-11-17
```

what I want to get is :

```
supp_id   name    phone         price       value   remain
1         test    0543642256    8000        4000    4000
2         test2   0543642211    2000        0       2000
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide some sample data in DDL/DML form for testing.

Comment: FYI, 3 part naming for columns is due [to be deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/); alias your objects and qualify your columns with that. Some *good* use of white space and line breaks really won't go amiss either.

Comment: The image datatype has been deprecated for 15 years - don't use it now!

Comment: @DaleK I updated the question, take a look please

Comment: @SMor , thank you for the advice, what I should use instead ??

Comment: @DaleK do you want the DDL for the 3 tables ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum the price and value separately, then interact with them. Don't kill yourself trying to do complicated summations and joins beforehand; you will get incorrect calculations if you joined them wrong.

```sql
SELECT 
  s.name,
  s.phone,
  inv.sumPrice,
  val.sumValue,
  isnull(inv.sumPrice, 0) - isnull(val.sumValue, 0) as sumProfit
FROM suppliers s
LEFT JOIN ( /* see this subquery, pretending to be a table */
           SELECT 
             supp_id,
             sum(price) as sumPrice
           FROM suppliers_invoices
           GROUP BY supp_id) inv on s.supp_id = inv.supp_id
LEFT JOIN ( /* see this subquery, pretending to be a table */
           SELECT 
             supp_id,
             sum([value]) as sumValue
           FROM suppliers_payments
           GROUP BY supp_id) val on s.supp_id = val.supp_id ;
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e7999/4/0)

Comment: Thank you for helping, and explaining the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to pre-aggregate in subqueries. One option uses lateral joins:

```
select s.*, si.price, sp.value, si.price - sp.value as remain
from suppliers s
cross apply (
    select coalesce(sum(si.price), 0) as price
    from suppliers_invoices si
    where si.supp_id = s.supp_id
) si
cross apply (
    select coalesce(sum(sp.value), 0) as value
    from suppliers_payments sp
    where sp.supp_id = s.supp_id
) sp
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing out on a left join instead of a inner join.

Please find the below query:

```
SELECT sup.name, sum(sup_inv.price), sum(sup_pay.value), sup.supp_id
FROM suppliers sup
left JOIN suppliers_invoices sup_inv
 ON sup.supp_id = sup_inv.supp_id 
left JOIN suppliers_payments sup_pay
ON sup.supp_id = sup_pay.supp_id 
group by sup.supp_id, sup.name;
```